# Правильная работа с JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Мне захотелось сделать так: все новости из базы данных скинуть в json-массив, а потом выводить всю кашу куда хочется с помощью js. У новостей свой айди, название и содержание. Покажите пример как можно все это сделать?
Хотелось бы формат типа: `1{'test', 'desc'},2{'test', 'desc'},3{'test', 'desc'},1{'test', 'desc'}`. Естественно не как у меня а как у json.

Спасибо за ответы, у меня тут в коде наверное банальная ошибка но я так и не пойму откуда она появляется.

```
<?php
$main = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world_project', 'world', 'yan6dw');
$result = $db->query("SELECT `id`,`title`,`content` FROM `News` LIMIT 10");
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
$news = [
  $row['id'] => [
    'title' => $row['title'],
    'text' => $row['content']
  ]];
}
die ($news);
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/world/w-0rld.ru/connect.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/world/w-0rld.ru/functions.php(2): include_once() #1 /home/world/w-0rld.ru/index.php(2): include_once('/home/world/w-0...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/world/w-0rld.ru/connect.php on line 3

Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получите в PHP ассоциативный массив нужного вида

```
$result = array(
  $news_id => array(
    'text' => $news_text,
    'desc' => $news_desc,
  ),
  // ...
)
```

Переведите его в JSON:

```
$json_data = json_encode( $result);
```

И отдайте в браузер либо прямо в теле страницы как часть скрипта:

```
<html>
...
<script>
    var news = <?php echo $json_data ?>;
    // и теперь можно получать новость:
    var html='', id;
    for( id in news) {
        html += '<div><h4>' + news[id].text + '</h4>';
        html += '<p>' + news[id].desc + '</p></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('b-news').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Или пусть скрипт из страницы ajax-запросом получает данные из отдельного url на сервере. Тогда добавьте соотв. заголовок ответу:

```
<?php
// ...
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_data;
```

Comment: Не увидел вашего ответа, когда писал свой :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы можете получить массив новостей, то сделать из него json не представляется сложным:

```
$news = [
  15 => [
    'title' => 'Title 1',
    'text' => 'text 15'
  ],
  18 => [
    'title' => 'Title 2',
    'text' => 'text 18'
  ]
];
$json = json_encode($news);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function json('запрос')
    {
        /* Соединение с БД */


        // Получение и возврат результатов
        $result = $db->query('запрос');
        $List = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $List[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $List[$i]['news'] = $row['news'];
            $List[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
            $List[$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $List;
    }
```

Comment: где здесь JSON, кроме названия функции?